# If $\lim_{n \to \infty }\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}= L$ then $A(L-\epsilon)^n< B(L+\epsilon)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

**Let $(x_n)$ be a strictly positive sequence and if $\lim_{n \to \infty }\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}= L$ and $0< \epsilon <L$ then $\exists A,B > 0 $ and $K\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n>K$, $A(L-\epsilon)^n\leq x_n \leq B(L+\epsilon)^n$**

My attempt:
Let $0< \epsilon <L$ be arbirary.
Then $\exists K $ such that $\forall n > K,\\$ $(l-\epsilon) <\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}<(l+\epsilon)$
And accordingly we have 
$$(l-\epsilon) <\frac{x_{n+2}}{x_{n+1}}<(l+\epsilon)$$
$$(l-\epsilon) <\frac{x_{n+3}}{x_{n+2}}<(l+\epsilon)$$
$$(l-\epsilon) <\frac{x_{n+4}}{x_{n+3}}<(l+\epsilon)$$
$$.$$
$$.$$
$$.$$
$$(l-\epsilon) <\frac{x_{n+n}}{x_{n+n-1}}<(l+\epsilon)$$

And by multiplying we get $(l-\epsilon)^n <\frac{x_{n+n}}{x_{n}}<(l+\epsilon)^n$.

But afterwards I couldn't proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x_K(l-\epsilon)^s< x_{K+s} < x_K(l+\epsilon )^s$

Let $x_K =A(l-\epsilon)^K$. For $B$, we do a similar.

Comment: Hi Lee, 
How do we select $A$ and would this method you suggest lead to the final solution of getting $x_n$ within the inequality?

Comment: $x_K,\ K,\ l,\ \epsilon$ are fixed so that $A$ is determined.